# OSX - Tor Guard and Little Snitch

Tags: macos, vpn, firewall

I have a question regarding two applications/services that I'm currently looking at.

Tor Guard is a VPN service.

Little Snitch is an OSX firewall.

Little snitch provides a gui window that shows you where in the world your traffic is destined for. Quite fun to watch. However after installing Tor Guard and connecting to their service, I'm still seeing a significant amount of traffic heading overseas and not to where my VPN is connected to.

I know Little Snitch operates at the application layer, but i'm wondering if I'm leaking loads of traffic, or there's something I'm missing here? I'm hoping for the latter.

Is there a good way of testing a VPN against the traffic your computer is generating/receiving that it's being funneled through the VPN? Would wireshark be the tool? And if so, how might I got about configuring it?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VPN service provides a tunneled, virtual link to your VPN provider. Traffic through that tunnel is NATed at the end and appears to the outside as originating from that end. It cannot normally be attributed to you, except by the VPN provider.

Little Snitch analyzes *local traffic* - there, the traffic is destined for the original location which is what you're seeing. The traffic is encapsulated for VPN and sent through the tunnel - you should also be seeing that. The latter is the only *remote traffic* an observer could see.

Basically, an outside, all-seeing observer sees you communicating with the tunnel end. He also sees the tunnel end (or some other, potentially even completely different address) communicating with the end destinations. However, seeing many inbound tunnels he cannot (easily) match the tunneled traffic to the end-destination traffic.

For you to see which traffic is observable from the outside, you should filter out (ignore) the VPN interface traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So could I say use wireshark and filter out packets that include the IP that my VPN has provided for me to see what is not being tunneled?

Comment: Works with wireshark, too (which captures a single interface only anyway), but I thought you were using Little Snitch to monitor. That should have some kind of filter as well.